# Will rc.local block until command finish execution?

Tags: linux, rc

Will rc.local wait for each command to finish, or the commands are executed like exec() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a normal shell script.   So they block or not, according to how the script invokes the commands (e.g. with/without `&`).

But exec also works differently to how you appear to think; `exec()` doesn't do anything asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

They block.  They can be run asynchronously by putting '&' at the end.