# how to create a systemd service for daily reboot?

Tags: systemd

I have a raspberry pi with RuneAudio. I would like to set up a daily automatic reboot. Since RuneOS uses systemd rather than cron, how can I do that with systemd?

Comment: execute sleep 86400 && reboot

Comment: Look at systemd timers : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous answers actually use systemd to do the reboot. The correct answer is

Create a service unit `/etc/systemd/system/scheduled-reboot.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Daily Reboot

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl --force reboot
```

A timer unit `/etc/systemd/system/scheduled-reboot.timer`

```
[Unit]
Description=Daily Reboot

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 00:00:00

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

And activate the timer

```
sudo systemctl enable --now scheduled-reboot.timer
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a bash script that runs on startup and sleeps 24 hours and restarts then.
Write a file that contains:

```
sleep 24h 
sudo reboot
```

save it as reboot24.sh, make it executable and attach the following line to  /etc/rc.loc

```
sudo bash /path/to/file/reboot24.sh
```

**Edit:** this is a description for Raspbian. Not sure if it works on RuneOS

Comment: This has two flaws: 1) It will [block the rc.local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790465/will-rc-local-block-until-command-finish-execution) script and 2) would reboot in 24h +(whatever time the reboot requires).. Solution: put `shutdown -r 3:00 &` to reboot daily at 3 o'clock non-blocking.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [installed package list](https://susestudio.com/a/teXzcf/runeos-2-0/packages?image_type=iso&version=1.0.0) cron should be installed by default.

If it's disabled just enable it by typing

```
sudo systemctl enable cron
```

then append this to your /etc/crontab file

```
 25 6    * * *   root reboot
```

this will reboot your system every day at 6:25.

Now restart cron

```
sudo systemctl restart cron
```